# Page redirect on second click not working

Tags: jquery, css

The basic structure of my menu looks like this in html:

```
<ul id="primary-menu">
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="/about"></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="primeaty-list">Primary</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$('ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e) {
if ($(window).width() < 701) {  
  if (!$(e.target).closest('ul').is('.sub-menu')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('important')) {
      $(this).addClass('important');
        //toggle the menu 
    } else {
      //redirect if second click 
      window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    }
  }
}
});
```

Here the css that should be applied:

```
.important ul.sub-menu{
    display:block;
}
.important{
    display: block;
}
```

When I click on the list item that has children, it prevents from redirecting to the page and adds a class to it the way I want. 
But when I click for the second time, it does not redirect to its relevant link.

How can I make it possible to redirect on the second click?

Comment: You probably need to put the full URL into the href.

Comment: I don't understand your description of the problem nor your question...Maybe it would be helpful to create a working snippet

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: You want to redirect on second click? Is this what you mean?

Comment: it's working on second click.redirecting fine (for both li's)

Comment: Also, that's not how you should put `ul` in `ul`, you can't just put an `ul` in `ul` like that. Inner `ul` elements should always be wrapped by a `li`. So your `HTML` code is not valid.

Comment: It's working on second click

Comment: Yes I wanna make it redirect to its relevant link on second click. On my side, when I click for the second time the link still remains relative

Comment: @Ragmah, maybe you should put the click on the anchor instead of the `li` element. You don't have anything to prevent on the `li`. I've added an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `e.preventDefault()` you need to use it on the `a` element, not on the `li`. Now you will have to replace the redirection code a bit by using `window.location = $(this).attr('href');`. See the snippet below please:

```js
$('ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children a').click(function(e) {
  if ($(window).width() < 901) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('ul').is('.sub-menu')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!$(this).hasClass('important')) {
        $(this).addClass('important');
        //toggle the menu 
      } else {
        //redirect if second click 
        console.log('redirected on second click', $(this).attr('href'));
        //window.location = $(this).attr('href');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.important ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.important {
  display: block;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="primary-menu">
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="/about">test</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="primeaty-list">Primary</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```